# Can somebody elaborate on the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have always had the understanding that you use `SELECT` to select columns from a table. However, I was thrown off when I saw `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. I understand what it does... but I don't understand how we can simply just ask for the last inserted id like that. Isn't it true that the `SELECT` keyword expects to see column names immediately afterwards... so how does that function call satisfy that requirement?

Comment: You can select any expression in MySQL, e.g., `SELECT 5+4;`.

Comment: I'm not sure why the question is so downvoted.  It seems like a sincere question from a Java programmer with a reasonable amount of experience on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Think of `SELECT` as meaning "gimme" and the rest makes sense.

Comment: Okay I was just reading http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx, and just when I thought I had it all covered... I was thrown off again. The page mentions that if the current id is 1, and you insert three more rows and then use `select last_insert_id()` it will give you the value `2` and not `4`. How does that work? Why shouldn't it be `4`? I thought this returned the latest id that was inserted.

Comment: Okay, re-reading it solved my issue. So if multiple rows were inserted, `last_insert_id()` returns the first row of the last insert statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement normally works with a `FROM` clause to select columns -- and expressions on columns and constants -- from rows in a table.

Without the `FROM` clause, a `SELECT` simply evaluates the expressions and returns one row.  The function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is simply an expression that returns a value, so:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

returns a result set with single row with a single (unnamed) column.

Some databases do not like the idea of a `SELECT` without a `FROM`.  Oracle is one of them.  It requires a `FROM` clause and provides a table with one column and one row.  MySQL also supports `dual`, so you could write:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
FROM dual;
```

This is handy, if you want to include a `WHERE` clause with the `SELECT` (the `WHERE` requires a `FROM` in MySQL).

Comment: Wow.. awesome. Thank you for that information. I think you mentioned that it is possible to specify 3 things with `SELECT`... namely column names (i.e. `select fname`), expressions (i.e. `select last_insert_id()`), and constants. However, why are those called expressions and not function calls... and secondly, do you have any examples of select statements with constants?

Comment: @Grateful . . . `select 1` is a select statement with a constant.  `select 1 as x` has a constant that is named.  And, a function call is simply one type of expression.

Comment: Oh... I see. Thank you once again.